# Calling batch AND checking values: The batch file keeps crashing, but the script seems okay

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So I'm creating a game with lots of variables, but I want the user to either be restricted access to and/or go to a certain place or area depending on the variables that are set.

I have all the places where you can go written up, yet for some reason, there seems to be some syntax error that I cannot recognise. Below is an example, but I have many slight variations throughout the game depending on what entity you have already killed or where you have set your hometown.

I do get an error message, but the program closes way too quickly for me to read what it says. I have tried recording the "crash", and slowed down the video, but the image wasn't the best quality. Something along the lines of "spawn0 is not recognised", which I'm assuming is related to the syntax.

A couple of the variable checkers do work, such as checking the level of your character before allowing you to enter the citadel for example (see below).

```
set /p cit1=
if %cit1% EQU 1 GOTO citadellvlcheck
if %cit1% EQU 2 GOTO SAVE_GAME_FILES_Masafkel
GOTO CIT_WARN

:citadellvlcheck
if %curlvl% LSS 50 GOTO citadellvlreq
if %curlvl% GEQ 50 GOTO entercitadel

:citadellvlreq
@echo off
color 0F
cls
echo.
echo  You must be level 50 or higher to enter the citadel.
pause > nul
GOTO MasafkelMenu-XC
```

But because I can't get the spawn check to work, or MasafkelMenu-XC to work, as soon as a user logs into the game, it instantly crashes. And the same goes for creating a user. You set your username, password, in-game email (just in case you forget your password), gender and even species; but it just crashes immediately after, not even creating the character batch file. Below are some examples.

```
:SpawnCheck
@echo off
Title Adrynia
Color 0F
cls
call %name1%.bat
if %spawn%=spawn0 GOTO SpawnMenu0
if %spawn%=spawn1 GOTO SpawnMenu0
if %spawn%=spawn2 GOTO SpawnMenu0
if %spawn%=spawn3 GOTO SpawnMenu0
if %spawn%=spawn4 GOTO SpawnMenu0
if %spawn%=spawn5 GOTO SpawnMenu0
if %spawn%=spawn6 GOTO SpawnMenu0
if %spawn%=spawn7 GOTO SpawnMenu0
if %spawn%=spawn8 GOTO SpawnMenu0
if %spawn%=spawn9 GOTO SpawnMenu0
if %spawn%=Groylle GOTO GroylleMenu
if %spawn%=Meprophia GOTO MeprophiaMenu
if %spawn%=HermitHut GOTO HermitHutMenu
if %spawn%=Masafkel GOTO MasafkelMenu-XC
if %spawn%=Crounver GOTO CrounverMenu
if %spawn%=Bobeindahl GOTO BobeindahlMenu
if %spawn%=Krontay GOTO KrontayMenu
if %spawn%=Slinguss GOTO SlingussMenu
if %spawn%=Tichyster GOTO TichysterMenu
if %spawn%=Houjing GOTO HoujingMenu
if %spawn%=flat1 GOTO FlatMenu1
if %spawn%=flat2 GOTO FlatMenu2
if %spawn%=flat3 GOTO FlatMenu3
if %spawn%=flat4 GOTO FlatMenu4
if %spawn%=flat5 GOTO FlatMenu5
if %spawn%=flat6 GOTO FlatMenu6
if %spawn%=flat7 GOTO FlatMenu7
if %spawn%=flat8 GOTO FlatMenu8
if %spawn%=flat9 GOTO FlatMenu9
if %spawn%=flat10 GOTO FlatMenu10
if %spawn%=house1 GOTO HouseMenu1
if %spawn%=house2 GOTO HouseMenu2
if %spawn%=house3 GOTO HouseMenu3
if %spawn%=house4 GOTO HouseMenu4
if %spawn%=house5 GOTO HouseMenu5
if %spawn%=house6 GOTO HouseMenu6
if %spawn%=house7 GOTO HouseMenu7
if %spawn%=house8 GOTO HouseMenu8
if %spawn%=house9 GOTO HouseMenu9
if %spawn%=house10 GOTO HouseMenu10
GOTO Error


:MasafkelMenu-XC
@echo off
color 0f
cls
call %name1%.bat
if %Criunthma%=0 GOTO MasafkelMenu
if %Criunthma%=1 GOTO Masafkel-CD
GOTO Error
```

If it is impossible to do such a thing in a batch file then so be it, but if it is is possible, I would like to at least give it my best attempt.

So, other than the game being a text-based game where the player uses his/her imagination to create a better sense of the game-world around them, and therefore hopefully enhance the gaming experience; I also like to use the coding of this game to learn new skills and test the limits of both batch scripting and my small, but gradually increasing knowledge of batch MS-DOS and batch scripting.

Now, when I did some tests run in cmd, this is what was shown: "Artemis.bat" is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program, or in batch file. =spawn0 was unexpected at this time. That appeared regardless of what you chose your username to be, however, when run by itself, it only said "=spawn0 was not expected at this time".

I don't understand how %spawnpoint%=spawn0 could not be recognised or could be unexpected as the character gets a spawnpoint assigned when it is created (in :CHAR_DATA) When you first create a character, :CHAR_DATA assigns you the spawn named "spawnpoint; but if you set a home town, or buy either a house or a flat, then your spawn will be set to that town or house/flat instead, so that when you start the game, you will start at your spawn.

```
:CHAR_DATA
set acc1g=0
set acc1m=Open
set acc2g=0
set acc2m=Open
set acc3g=0
set acc3m=Open
set acc4g=0
set acc4m=Open
set acc5g=0
set acc5m=Open
set cost=
set cost1=
set gcho=
set echo=
set e2cho=
set e1=
set armour=30
set origarmour=30
set Cyrax=0
set Fregwin=0
set Zeschka=0
set Agnorr=0
set Grehln=0
set Meiqa=0
set Lothin=0
set Skatha=0
set Triffyn=0
set Glieza=0
set Areya=0
set Exin=0
set Yewvar=0
set Smuggler=0
set Qwaen=0
set Oracle=0
set Antharr=0
set Cadell=0
set Rhyghan=0
set Helori=0
set Chaerron=0
set Cyntheyrr=0
set Mureh=0
set Llaellyn=0
set Bechim=0
set Brathach=0
set Albreqi=0
set Tausir=0
set Mivrailoksh=0
set Khaen=0
set Criunthma=0
set Vunada=0
set VT=0
set VC=G
set ls1=0
set killcount=0
set ttlbosskill=0
set ttlmonstkill=0
set ttlkills=0
set goodness=0
set evilness=0
set morality=neutral
set ls2=0
set la1=0
set la2=0
set orighp=100
set hp=100
set origsp=25
set sp=25
set armtype=None
set swordtype=Your
set skind=hand
set buyword1=hi
set buyword2=hi
set curlvl=1
set aan=a
set bankqharri=0
set destination=SAVE_GAME_FILES1
set destination2=SAVE_GAME_FILES1
set swordchoice=Nothing
set swordchoice2=Nothing
set swordchoice3=Nothing
set swordexist=Nothing
set rent=0
set sprice=0
set armchoice=No
set armchoice2=Amour
set aprice=0
set playerxp=0
set xpuntil=1000
set origxp=0
set money=0
set platos=0
set lovana=0
set credits=0
set key=0
set dmge=10
set origdmge=10
set dr=0
set spawn=spawn0
set rests=0
set sleep=100
set rochtain=0
set beer=0
set wine=0
set spirits=0
set naeprahv=0
set drunk=0
set ID=0
set day=42
set week=5
set month=12
set year=73734
set status=alive
set gmail=0
set hbone=0
set dhide=0
set rtab=0
set food=0
set cigarette=0
set seaweed=0
set weedcig=0
set rfood=0
set bait=0
set ea=None
set potion=0
set copperingot=0
set ironingot=0
set steelingot=0
set bronzeingot=0
set brassingot=0
set tiningot=0
set silveringot=0
set goldingot=0
set zincingot=0
set manganeseingot=0
set aluminiumingot=0
set chromiumingot=0
set nickelingot=0
set refinedcopper=0
set refinediron=0
set refinedtin=0
set refinedsilver=0
set refinedgold=0
set refinedzinc=0
set refinedmanganese=0
set refinedaluminium=0
set refinedsilicon=0
set refinedchromium=0
set refinednickel=0
set seed=0
set bow=0
set fur=0
set gem=0
set log=0
set wood=0
set copperore=0
set ironore=0
set tinore=0
set silverore=0
set goldore=0
set zincore=0
set manganeseore=0
set aluminiumore=0
set siliconore=0
set chromiumore=0
set nickelore=0
set morb=0
set arm1=0
set arm2=0
set arm3=0
set arm4=0
set arm5=0
set arm6=0
set arm7=0
set arm8=0
set arm9=0
set arm10=0
set arm11=0
set arm12=0
set ma1=0
set ma2=0
set ma3=0
set ma4=0
set ma5=0
set ma6=0
set ma7=0
set ma8=0
set ma9=0
set ma10=0
set ms1=0
set ms2=0
set ms3=0
set ms4=0
set ms5=0
set ms6=0
set ms7=0
set ms8=0
set ms9=0
set ms10=0
set sword1=0
set sword2=0
set sword3=0
set sword4=0
set sword5=0
set sword6=0
set sword7=0
set sword8=0
set sword9=0
set sword10=0
set sword11=0
set sword12=0
set axxx=0
set pgmail=300
set phbone=550
set pdhide=750
set prtab=250
set ppotion=200
set pfood=100
set pingot=473
set pseed=150
set prfood=100
set pbait=2
set pfur=200
set pore=500
set plog=275
set pgem=500
set pbow=713
set pmorb=15000
set Woodcuttinglvl=1
set Woodcuttingxpremain=5000
set Woodcuttingxpgain=20
set Woodcuttingcurxp=0
set Woodcuttingxpleft=5000
set Cooklvl=1
set Cookxpremain=5000
set Cookxpgain=50
set Cookcurxp=0
set Cookxpleft=5000
set Fishinglvl=1
set Fishingxpremain=5000
set Fishingxpgain=50
set Fishingcurxp=0
set Fishingxpleft=5000
set Mininglvl=1
set Miningxpremain=5000
set Miningxpgain=50
set Miningcurxp=0
set Miningxpleft=100
set Smeltinglvl=1
set Smeltingxpremain=5000
set Smeltingxpgain=50
set Smeltingcurxp=0
set Smeltingxpleft=5000
set Thievinglvl=1
set Thievingxpremain=10000
set Thievingxpgain=25
set Thievingcurxp=0
set Thievingxpleft=10000
set ttllvl=13
set prestige=0
set maxprestige=NO
GOTO SpawnCheck
```

The above is used to set up the character log file, and the code below is used to save the current variables in the character log file that is currently being used.

```
:SAVE_GAME_FILES1
(
echo set username1=%username1%
echo set password1=%password1%
echo set mailver=%mailver%
echo set species=%species%
:CHAR_DATA
echo set acc1g=%acc1g%
echo set acc1m=%acc1m%
echo set acc2g=%acc2g%
echo set acc2m=%acc2m%
echo set acc3g=%acc3g%
echo set acc3m=%acc3m%
echo set acc4g=%acc4g%
echo set acc4m=%acc4m%
echo set acc5g=%acc5g%
echo set acc5m=%acc5m%
echo set cost1=%cost1%
echo set cost=%cost%
echo set gcho=%gcho%
echo set echo=%echo%
echo set e2cho=%e2cho%
echo set e1=%e1%
echo set armour=%armour%
echo set origarmour=%origarmour%
echo set Cyrax=%Cyrax%
echo set Fregwin=%Fregwin%
echo set Zeschka=%Zeschka%
echo set Agnorr=%Agnorr%
echo set Grehln=%Grehln%
echo set Meiqa=%Meiqa%
echo set Lothin=%Lothin%
echo set Skatha=%Skatha%
echo set Triffyn=%Triffyn%
echo set Glieza=%Glieza%
echo set Areya=%Areya%
echo set Exin=%Exin%
echo set Yewvar=%Yewvar%
echo set Smuggler=%Smuggler%
echo set Qwaen=%Qwaen%
echo set Oracle=%Oracle%
echo set Antharr=%Antharr%
echo set Cadell=%Cadell%
echo set Rhyghan=%Rhyghan%
echo set Helori=%Helori%
echo set Chaerron=%Chaerron%
echo set Cyntheyrr=%Cyntheyrr%
echo set Mureh=%Mureh%
echo set Llaellyn=%Llaellyn%
echo set Bechim=%Bechim%
echo set Brathach=%Brathach%
echo set Albreqi=%Albreqi%
echo set Tausir=%Tausir%
echo set Mivrailoksh=%Mivrailoksh%
echo set Khaen=%Khaen%
echo set Criunthma=%Criunthma%
echo set Vunada=%Vunada%
echo set VT=%VT%
echo set VC=%VC%
echo set ls1=%ls1%
echo set killcount=%killcount%
echo set ttlbosskill=%ttlbosskill%
echo set ttlmonstkill=%ttlmonstkill%
echo set ttlkills=%ttlkills%
echo set goodness=%goodness%
echo set evilness=%evilness%
echo set morality=%morality%
echo set ls2=%ls2%
echo set la1=%la1%
echo set la2=%la2%
echo set orighp=%orighp%
echo set hp=%hp%
echo set origsp=%origsp%
echo set sp=%sp%
echo set armtype=%armtype%
echo set swordtype=%swordtype%
echo set skind=%skind%
echo set buyword1=%buyword1%
echo set buyword2=%buyword2%
echo set curlvl=%curlvl%
echo set aan=%aan%
echo set bankqharri=%bankqharri%
echo set destination=SAVE_GAME_FILES1
echo set destination2=SAVE_GAME_FILES1
echo set swordchoice=Nothing
echo set swordchoice2=Nothing
echo set swordchoice3=Nothing
echo set swordexist=Nothing
echo set rent=%rent%
echo set sprice=%sprice%
echo set armchoice=%armchoice%
echo set armchoice2=%armchoice2%
echo set aprice=%aprice%
echo set playerxp=0
echo set xpuntil=1000
echo set origxp=%origxp%
echo set money=%money%
echo set platos=%platos%
echo set lovana=%lovana%
echo set ruflarii=%ruflarii%
echo set credits=%credits%
echo set key=%key%
echo set dmge=%dmge%
echo set origdmge=%origdmge%
echo set dr=%dr%
echo set spawn=%spawn%
echo set rests=%rests%
echo set sleep=%sleep%
echo set rochtain=%rochtain%
echo set beer=%beer%
echo set wine=%wine%
echo set spirits=%spirits%
echo set naeprahv=%naeprahv%
echo set drunk=%drunk%
echo set ID=%ID%
echo set day=%week%
echo set week=%week%
echo set month=%month%
echo set year=%year%
echo set status=%status%
echo set gmail=%gmail%
echo set hbone=%hbone%
echo set dhide=%dhide%
echo set rtab=%rtab%
echo set food=%food%
echo set cigarette=%cigarette%
echo set seaweed=%seaweed%
echo set weedcig=%weedcig%
echo set rfood=%rfood%
echo set bait=%bait%
echo set ea=%ea%
echo set potion=%potion%
echo set copperingot=%copperingot%
echo set ironingot=%ironingot%
echo set steelingot=%steelingot%
echo set bronzeingot=%bronzeingot%
echo set brassingot=%brassingot%
echo set tiningot=%tiningot%
echo set silveringot=%silveringot%
echo set goldingot=%goldingot%
echo set zincingot=%zincingot%
echo set manganeseingot=%manganeseingot%
echo set aluminiumingot=%aluminiumingot%
echo set chromiumingot=%chromiumingot%
echo set nickelingot=%nickelingot%
echo set refinedcopper=%refinedcopper%
echo set refinediron=%refinediron%
echo set refinedtin=%refinedtin%
echo set refinedsilver=%refinedsilver%
echo set refinedgold=%refinedgold%
echo set refinedzinc=%refinedzinc%
echo set refinedmanganese=%refinedmanganese%
echo set refinedaluminium=%refinedaluminium%
echo set refinedsilicon=%refinedsilicon%
echo set refinedchromium=%refinedchromium%
echo set refinednickel=%refinednickel%
echo set seed=%seed%
echo set bow=%bow%
echo set fur=%fur%
echo set gem=%gem%
echo set log=%log%
echo set wood=%wood%
echo set copperore=%copperore%
echo set ironore=%ironore%
echo set tinore=%tinore%
echo set silverore=%silverore%
echo set goldore=%goldore%
echo set zincore=%zincore%
echo set manganeseore=%manganeseore%
echo set aluminiumore=%aluminiumore%
echo set siliconore=%siliconore%
echo set chromiumore=%chromiumore%
echo set nickelore=%nickelore%
echo set morb=%morb%
echo set arm1=%arm1%
echo set arm2=%arm2%
echo set arm3=%arm3%
echo set arm4=%arm4%
echo set arm5=%arm5%
echo set arm6=%arm6%
echo set arm7=%arm7%
echo set arm8=%arm8%
echo set arm9=%arm9%
echo set arm10=%arm10%
echo set arm11=%arm11%
echo set arm12=%arm12%
echo set ma1=%ma1%
echo set ma2=%ma2%
echo set ma3=%ma3%
echo set ma4=%ma4%
echo set ma5=%ma5%
echo set ma6=%ma6%
echo set ma7=%ma7%
echo set ma8=%ma8%
echo set ma9=%ma9%
echo set ma10=%ma10%
echo set ms1=%ms1%
echo set ms2=%ms2%
echo set ms3=%ms3%
echo set ms4=%ms4%
echo set ms5=%ms5%
echo set ms6=%ms6%
echo set ms7=%ms7%
echo set ms8=%ms8%
echo set ms9=%ms9%
echo set ms10=%ms10%
echo set sword1=%sword1%
echo set sword2=%sword2%
echo set sword3=%sword3%
echo set sword4=%sword4%
echo set sword5=%sword5%
echo set sword6=%sword6%
echo set sword7=%sword7%
echo set sword8=%sword8%
echo set sword9=%sword9%
echo set sword10=%sword10%
echo set sword11=%sword11%
echo set sword12=%sword12%
echo set axxx=%axxx%
echo set pgmail=%pgmail%
echo set phbone=%phbone%
echo set pdhide=%pdhide%
echo set prtab=%prtab%
echo set ppotion=%ppotion%
echo set pingot=%pingot%
echo set pfood=%pfood%
echo set prfood=%prfood%
echo set pbait=%pbait%
echo set pseed=%pseed%
echo set pfur=%pfur%
echo set pore=%pore%
echo set pbow=%pbow%
echo set plog=%plog%
echo set pgem=%pgem%
echo set pmorb=%pmorb%
echo set Woodcuttinglvl=%Woodcuttinglvl%
echo set Woodcuttingxpremain=%Woodcuttingxpremain%
echo set Woodcuttingxpgain=%Woodcuttingxpgain%
echo set Woodcuttingcurxp=%Woodcuttingcurxp%
echo set Woodcuttingxpleft=%woodcuttingxpleft%
echo set Cooklvl=%Cooklvl%
echo set Cookxpremain=%Cookxpremain%
echo set Cookxpgain=%Cookxpgain%
echo set Cookcurxp=%Cookcurxp%
echo set Cookxpleft=%Cookxpleft%
echo set Fishinglvl=%Fishinglvl%
echo set Fishingxpremain=%Fishingxpremain%
echo set Fishingxpgain=%Fishingxpgain%
echo set Fishingcurxp=%Fishingcurxp%
echo set Fishingxpleft=%Fishingxpleft%
echo set Mininglvl=%Mininglvl%
echo set Miningxpremain=%Miningxpremain%
echo set Miningxpgain=%Miningxpgain%
echo set Miningcurxp=%Miningcurxp%
echo set Miningxpleft=%Miningxpleft%
echo set Smeltinglvl=%Smeltinglvl%
echo set Smeltingxpremain=%Smeltingxpremain%
echo set Smeltingxpgain=%Smeltingxpgain%
echo set Smeltingcurxp=%Smeltingcurxp%
echo set Smeltingxpleft=%Smeltingxpleft%
echo set Thievinglvl=%Thievinglvl%
echo set Thievingxpremain=%Thievingxpremain%
echo set Thievingxpgain=%Thievingxpgain%
echo set Thievingcurxp=%Thievingcurxp%
echo set Thievingxpleft=%Thievingxpleft%
echo set ttllvl=%ttllvl%
echo set prestige=%prest%
echo set maxprestige=%maxprest%
)>%username1%.bat
GOTO SpawnCheck
```

The logging in section seems to be fine, but just in case, here's the code for that.

```
:login
cls
set /p name1="Username: "
if not exist "%name1%.bat" (
echo.
echo That is not a valid Username.
timeout /T 3 > nul
GOTO entergame1
)
set /p pass1="Password: "
call %name1%.bat
if %password1% NEQ %pass1% (
echo.
echo That is not a valid Password, please enter your in-game email.
timeout /T 3 > nul
GOTO emailver
)
GOTO SAVE_GAME_FILES1

:emailver
cls
echo.
set /p mailver="In-game Email: "
call %name1%.bat
if %mailver% NEQ %mailver% (
echo.
echo That is not a valid in-game email address.
timeout /T 3 > nul
cls
GOTO entergame1
)
GOTO SAVE_GAME_FILES1
```

The character creator section also seems to be functional, but as soon as it goes to :SpawnCheck it crashes.

```
:createuser
@echo off
Title Adrynia
color 0F
cls
echo.
echo What would you like your Username to be?
set /p username1=
set v1f=0

:checkforspaces
set x=!v1f!
set Letter%v1f%=!username1:~%x%,1!
if "!Letter%v1f%!" EQU " " (
echo.
echo.
echo Sorry, you cant use spaces in your Username.
pause > nul
GOTO createuser
)
if NOT "!Letter%v1f%!" EQU "" (
set /a v1f=%v1f%+1
GOTO checkforspaces
)
echo.
echo What would you like your Password to be?
set /p password1=
echo.
echo What would you like your in-game email to be? (This will be used as secondary login/verification option).
set /a rpc=1
set /p mailver=
GOTO choosespecies2


:choosespecies2
@echo off
Title Adrynia
color 0F
cls
echo.
echo What species would you like to be?
echo.
echo 1) Adrynian
echo 2) Bryniskan
echo 3) Cruvoshnian
echo 4) Gangloidian
echo 5) Human
echo 6) Hybrid
echo 7) Sehyapov
echo.
set /p input=
if %input% EQU 1 set species=Adrynian && GOTO CHAR_DATA
if %input% EQU 2 set species=Bryniskan && GOTO CHAR_DATA
if %input% EQU 3 set species=Cruvoshnian && GOTO CHAR_DATA
if %input% EQU 4 set species=Gangloidian && GOTO CHAR_DATA
if %input% EQU 5 set species=Human && GOTO CHAR_DATA
if %input% EQU 6 set species=Hybrid && GOTO CHAR_DATA
if %input% EQU 7 set species=Sehyapov && GOTO CHAR_DATA
GOTO choosespecies2
```

At the moment, the only place where the errors have occurred is in :SpawnCheck and :Masafkel-XC but I have kept the other sections of the code showing just in case there is any other errors that may contribute to my current problem.

I understand that batch scripting is an archaic form of coding - especially for an RPG-style game - but any help or corrections, and/or information why this could be like this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You're going to have to post some more detail on 'crashes' do you get an error message? Do you have any log files you can check? I suggest that batch may not be the best language to do this in. Have you considered HTA? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application it's an old technology but at least you get a UI.

Comment: ... than add some jquery and you've got a blockbuster. Here's a library that looks optimised for RPG's: http://www.jqueryrain.com/2015/12/rpg-js-rpg-2d-browser-with-html5-canvas/

Comment: Thank you. I do get an error message, but the program closes way too quickly for me to read what it says. I have tried recording the "crash", and slowed down the video, but the image wasn't the best quality. Something along the lines of "spawn0 is not recognised", which I'm assuming is related to the syntax. Unfortunately, I don't have any log files.

As for how batch is probably not being the best coding language... Yes, I am aware, and understand that it is extremely archaic, yet my game revolves around the fact that it is a batch-game.

Comment: OK, so put `PAUSE` in your batch file, then the screen won't close until you press a key.... or if you don't know where that is, start a command line prompt and type in the batch file there, and when it finishes it won't close the window it'll leave it open

Comment: for troubleshooting don't run with a doubleclick, but open a `cmd` window and run it manually, so the window stays open to read any errormessages. Once you identify a special block of code that fails, `echo on` might be a good idea to exactly see, what happens.

Comment: There is nothing in the shown code, that could possibly create those errormessages. You may want to edit your question to reflect the affected code (we can't help you with code that we can't see).

Comment: Puhh - please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your chances of getting a good answer would raise considerably. Your main problem seems to be that `artemis.bat` could not be found. The following errormessages are because some variables not being defined (as they get defined in the said `artemis.bat`). Check if your working folder is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

i solved your problem.
i ran a simple test with your lines of code, here are the tests

working test:

```
@echo off
set spawn= spawn0
if %spawn% == spawn0 GOTO SpawnMenu0

:SpawnMenu0
cls
echo it works
pause
exit
```

your original non working test:

```
@echo off
set spawn= spawn0
if %spawn%=spawn0 GOTO SpawnMenu0

:SpawnMenu0
cls
echo it works
pause
exit
```

your problem is the equal sign

```
if %spawn%=spawn0 GOTO SpawnMenu0
```

it should have a space after the variable then two equal signs side by side, then another space like this:

```
if %spawn% == spawn0 GOTO SpawnMenu0
```

i hope i helped fix your problem in SpawnCheck

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. it worked perfectly. I thought it must have been something to do with my poor code writing, but I couldn't put my finger on it (because I didn't have the knowledge). Wow, how could I miss such a simple mistake? Ha! Thanks, you've helped a lot, now I can get on with business.